# Rotate, then resize directory of images with ImageMagick and bash

Tags: bash, imagemagick, image-resizing

I'd like to check and see if all images in a directory are landscape or portrait, and them to portrait if they are in landscape. After rotating, I want to resize the images so that it is a particular resolution (118 dots per cm) and horizontal dimension (9cm).

**In summary:**

- All images in portrait
- Resolution of 118 dots per cm
- 9cm Horizontal dimension

I know identify can pull the dimensions, but I'm not sure how to pull the individual height/width values.

Basically, I'd like to do this:

```
FILES=/path/to/*
for i in $FILES
identify -format "%f,%w,%h"
do
  if [%w -gt %h]
    then
    convert -rotate 90 $i

  mogrify -resize -density ?x? -resolution? -PixelsPerCm $i $i_resized.jpg
done
```

Ultimately, I would like to tile these to a 1m x any lenth document for printing from a plotter. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
read f w h < <(identify -format "%f %w %h" "$imagefile")
if (( $w > $h )) ; then
    # convert
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The image dimensions appear to be the third column in the `identify` output:

```
$ identify someimage.jpg
someimage.jpg JPEG 600x450 600x450+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 205KB 0.010u 0:00.009
```

So you can use `cut` to extract the dimensions:

```
f_size=$(identify $f | cut -f3 -d' ')
```

This would give you something ike `600x450`.  There are a variety of ways to separate these values.  For example:

```
f_width=${f_size%x*}
f_height=${f_size#*x}
```

This is even easier with the `-format` argument:

```
set -- $(identify -format '%w %h')
f_width=$1
f_height=$2
```

Comment: thanks. just for the -format bit myself [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/getting-image-size-imagemagick-352671/). Are you familiar with resizing by print dimension/resolution, rather than pixel dimension? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  You know your target resolution (118 dots per cm), so calculating the appropriate pixel dimension for a target print dimension would seem to be as simple as `<desired dimension in cm> * 118`.

Comment: Ahh, right. So something like `convert -size 1062x -units pixelspercentimeter -density 118x118 image.jpg image_new.jpg`?

Comment: I was thinking something like `convert -size $(( $f_width * 118 ))x$(( $f_height * 118 )) ...`.  And I'm not familiar enough with the `density` and `units` options to comment on those.

Comment: William's solution using read and `<(...)` is possibly a better way of getting the information from `identify` into variables.

Comment: it looks like  I would need to use `-resample` to change the printing resolution, rather than `-density`, along with `-resize`, rather than `-size`. The 1062 = 9cm*118 points/cm, with the `1062x` meaning to resize the height proportional to the width. So... `convert -resize 1062x -units pixelspercentimeter -resample 118x118 image.jpg image_new.jpg`. The file still seems to be coming out bigger than I wanted though, at 1700+ pixels.